Can I notch out my door frame to fit a storm door?
I have a new construction house and the door frame is 35 1/4" wide but the storm door i bought (Anderson 3000 series) is 35 9/16" wide. can I just take the router and notch out 3/8"x1" on one side of the frame as and paint it then install the storm door as normal?
Or would that cause it to look too lopsided, and should I do a 3/16" notch on both sides? Would that not work or is there an easier option?
Also I can't return it because Home Depot doesn't do returns on special orders since they don't stock this storm door. And the next size smaller door is too small so it's not like I can order a smaller door anyway.


Doing both sides will work.  The problem is if those boards are structural or decorative.  If decorative, they might not hold up to a door being used.  They do look a bit odd to me.

I have run into this issue myself.  If you are good with a router, cut a notch .  One side or both will not make a difference visually. The difference is only 3/16 of an inch. You are correct in priming and painting the bare wood to seal it from the elements.

I doubt the boards are structural, given the jointing at the corners.

That's an ... interesting ... architectural detail. I agree that it looks decorative rather than structural.
